# is it possible to call a modal using its attribute data-value instead of the div id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following function for calling the modal"

```
function openModal(x) {
(function ($) {

    $('#alarm').modal('show'); 
    })(jQuery);
```

}

and for the modal:

```
 <div id="alarm" class="modal fade modal-alert" data-value="'.$element['eventId'].'">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            Title
                        </div>
                         <div class="modal-body" id="boxPopUpPushCommand" style="text-align:left !important">
                            Body texts here 


                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Trying to open a specific modal using the data-value and not the id?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could with [`Jquery Attr Selector`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_equal_value.asp)

```
$('div[data-value=modalDataValue]').modal('show')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do like

```
$('#alarm[data-value=YOUR_VALUE_YOU_GET_VIA_PHP]').modal('show')
```

You can learn more about selectors at https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

> I suggest you get the data via an ID `$(#alarm)` that is unique in the document.